# How to send mail from shared email account?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, mailitem

I am trying send several items at the same time.

I have two mail addresses in my Outlook. The first is a personal work mail (like j.doe@company.com) and second is a shared mail account (like support@company.com).

I tried:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailMessage = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
Set oAccount = Session.accounts.Item(2)
objMailMessage.SendUsingAccount = oAccount
objMailMessage.display
```

I found **this won't work with shared email accounts**.

Most forums advise to use `.SentOnBehalfOfName`. When I try it on one email, the email has something like this in the Sender box `j.doe@company.com - Sent on behalf of name: "support@company.com`.

When I send mail from Outlook manually, it only shows the shared account on the received message. (It is not a big deal, but would be nicer if the code would work in the same style as manually.)

Also, when I put the code in a loop, **half mails are sent with shared accounts and half with personal account**.

And here is the code with `.SentOnBehalfOfName` which is going to be looped.

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailMessage = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
With objMailMessage
    .To = email
    .Subject = msgSubj
    .CC = ccp
    .BCC = "support@company.com"
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "support@company.com"
    .HTMLBody = msgText & "<br>" & "<br>" & msgSign
    .Attachments.Add path
    If rev > 0 Then
        .Save
    Else
        .Send
    End If
End With
```

Comment: What error do you get with the first code? The second code does not show enough to support " half mails are sent with shared accounts and half with personal account. [mcve]

Comment: As I remember, it does not see the second account, instead of error it just uses the only available (personal) account. When I tried to loop over Session.accounts.Items printing Item names, it only showed the private account. However, when in Outlook I change the shared account to any other, like my second personal account, it works.

Comment: If it does not see the second account you may have added a mailbox. To add an account. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b

Comment: I cannot add the second account separately, It is a shared account and it is added automatically when i add my personal work account. And i can send using that account from outlook itself, but not from vba

Answer (score 1):

This code attempts to ensure the .SentOnBehalfOf is consistent.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sendFromOtherMailbox()

    ' Code in Outlook, not called from another application

    Dim objMailMessage As mailItem
    Dim uMailbox As recipient

    ' Should not be necessary but this is used later to ensure
    ' the entry in .SentOnBehalfOfName is what you think it is.
    Set uMailbox = Session.CreateRecipient("Preferably display name here rather than email address.")

    uMailbox.Resolve

    ' An email address always resolves so the "If Resolved" test is not useful
    '  if an email address was used in .CreateRecipient
    If uMailbox.Resolved Then

        Set objMailMessage = CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With objMailMessage

            .Subject = "send From Other Mailbox"
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = uMailbox
            .Display

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```